# Why was the "value-added model" algorithm kept secret?

Tags: united-states, education

This [TED presentation](https://www.ted.com/talks/cathy_o_neil_the_era_of_blind_faith_in_big_data_must_end/transcript#t-147124) says that the New York Department of Education is using a secret algorithm to evaluate teachers:

> (..) teachers were being scored with a complex, **secret algorithm**
>   called the "value-added model (..)

I have looked for this algorithm and there is some criticism surrounding it ([Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/patricia-mcguire/teacher-evaluations_b_1328456.html?guccounter=1)):

> An algorithm is an automatic way to determine results. No need to have
>   those pesky human factors like judgment, emotion, discernment,
>   understanding, empathy, sympathy, critical reasoning involved.

While using or not an algorithm for evaluation is clearly debatable, I am interested mostly in the not being public part. This sounds strange as teachers do not know what they should improve if they are penalized by it.

**Question:** Why was the "value-added model" algorithm kept secret?

Comment: what does this have to do with governments?

Comment: @KDog it is a policy of public employee evaluations.

Comment: Can you be more clear please than these are public schools, and in what jurisdictions.  For the way the question is laid out, it could be a teacher at a corporation or pretty much anything at all.

Comment: And who owns the IP on the algo?

Comment: @KDog - deciding how to evaluate public employees seems like a political decision. Also, what does IP mean in this context?

Comment: @Alexei  Intellectual Property rights

Comment: @KDog In general, there is no real IP on algorithms (although *implementations* can be copyrighted). It's probably a secret to prevent teachers from attempting to game the algorithm artificially inflate their score.

Comment: I’m voting to close as a “motivation” question.  The only people who know why we’re the ones who decided it. “What reasons were given by the city/state/agency?” Would be more answerable.

Comment: @MartinTournoij if there is money being paid for the evaluation there is an incentive to conceal the algorithm precisely because there is less legal protection; it would be a trade secret which only are protected by law if they are protected in practice.

Comment: The [general ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_modeling#Method) behind these types of evaluations are known, and there isn't [a single secret algorithm](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2743034/) used by everyone. Different groups could have different reasons behind keeping their version secret, like trying to prevent someone from gaming the system or avoiding criticism for bad algorithms.

Comment: I dont know enough details to know if/why this specifically would have been done.  But one reason why you would hide the details of an imperfect algorithm is to prevent people from "gaming the system" or "playing to the test".  Basically if there is no knowledge of what is analyzed, people have to act normally and just hope that the magic black-box doesnt overlook their work.  Thats all they can do.  If they know the algorithm, they can focus on only things that the algorithm grades while ignoring other things, even if those other things are actually really important.

Comment: @Tal - yes, it makes perfect sense and this is probably the best answer I can receive.

Comment: @KDog It seems clear that this is a public policy question. According to the article, the New York Department of Education used this approach to score teachers. So the policy question is, "why was it a secret?".

Comment: @indigochild Probably, but I shouldn't have to read the article to figure that out.  That's what I am saying.

Comment: @Tal I agree. BTW that is essentially what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law says: "When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure."

Comment: @Tal - Seems like you have the start of an excellent answer there.  You should consider writing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algorithm is kept secret because it's developed by a private company and as such proprietary ([source](https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/evaas.html)).

As far as I know this is the system used by NY Board of Education, however I was not able to confirm it yet. But if it is then it answers your question: it is a product on which many fortunes depend.

Comment: Same reason why we can't (or "couldn't," if that has changed) look at source code in voting machines to make sure they are honestly tabulating votes.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - Well, in some countries there is a requirement to keep votes on paper, too (in case of machines printouts). But from experiences in voting in my home country I can tell you that doesn't matter. Stalin said that who's counting the votes matters, not who votes. You wouldn't believe what's going on there. One can also asks Scots - their independence vote was as fine a racket as possible...

Comment: Believe me, I'm not claiming that the USA way for stuff like this is the desirable mode, at all.

Answer (score 2):

One reason to keep scoring algorithms like this secret is to reduce the ability for people to "game" your system by performing poorly but scoring highly. By keeping an algorithm like this a secret, it hopefully encourages people to simply perform their best and hope the algorithm reflects that.

Comment: If the algorithm can be gamed in such a manner, that indicates that it's not fit for purpose and should be fixed.

Comment: @Vikki All possible algorithms are likely to be gameable, it'd be very difficult to come up with something that's impossible to game.  Consider how many people work on ensuring that actual games are balanced, and yet people still manage to min-max them in undesirable and unexpected ways even *without* significant financial advantages.